# How to write to csv using multiple dictionaries?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I know how to write one dictionary into a csv file but what if I need to use values from multiple dictionaries?

currently this is the code I am using:

```
for i , j in test.items():
            writer.writerow({'Patient ID': i, 'Total visits': j})
for key,value in frq.items():
            writer.writerow({'Total unique physicians': value})
```

this prints out the csv while skipping a section and prints the unique physicians on the second section.
for example:

```
patient ID    total visits  total unique physicians
5                 2
5                 3
4                 4
5                 4
patient ID    total visits  total unique physicians
                                 1
                                 2
                                 3
                                 4
```

I want this:

```
patient ID    total visits  total unique physicians
5                 2              1
5                 3              2
4                 4              3
5                 4              4
```

Does anyone know a way that I can write a csv file using multiple dictionaries? I have other dictionaries in this format that I will need to use this method. I can only use import csv, os, and string modules so no pandas.

Comment: I would start by researching what the zip() method does. Worst case, you just do that "by hand". But the whole thing looks a bit suspicious. Are you sure that the values of your third column really "match" the key column of the other dict?

Comment: @GhostCat I took zip out I realized I copied the old code. Both of them are dictionaries. Yes, they do match. I ran a test copy and they were the same. I don't have different keys for the dictionary but I do have different values.

Comment: Then just iterate the keys of the first dict, and pull values from all the dicts you want to print within your own loop?

Comment: If they match, for each row, update one dictionary from the other dictionary to merge them, then use the merged dictionary with writerow.

Answer (score 0):

`writer.writerow` writes a new line to CSV file and moves to the next line. There is no way to "go back" and use `writer.writerow` to modify an existing line. You first need to compose a dictionary with all items that you need, and then call `writer.writerow` with it. For example:

```
for ((patient_id, total_visits), (_, total_unique_physicians)) in zip(test.items(), frq.items()):
    writer.writerow({
        'Patient ID': patient_id,
        'Total visits': total_visits,
        'Total unique physicians': total_unique_physicians,
    })
```

Though, you need to pay attention that items in `test` and `frq` dictionaries go in the same order.